# como bloquear una opcion de calcular hasta que no se seleccione un RadioButton?

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

hola buenas me ando haciendo un programa de calculo donde tengo dos radio button y ocupo que el usuario deba seleccionar uno o sino la opcion de calcular no se habilita

el problema es que cuando son JTEXTFIELD si se como hacerlo pero como estos son dos botones nose como validar que se daba seleccionar uno o otro para que se habilite la casiilla de calcular

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ambos JRadioButton deben estar dentro de `ButtonGroup` para seleccionar sólo uno de ellos.

```
ButtonGroup grupo= new ButtonGroup(); 
grupo.add(jRadioButton1);
grupo.add(jRadioButton2);
```

2. El JButton no debe estar habilitado.

```
public OcultarBoton() {
        initComponents();
        grupo.add(jRadioButton1);
        grupo.add(jRadioButton2);
        
        jButton1.setEnabled(false); //sin Habilitar
    }
```

3. Activar el evento mouseClicked para cada JRadioButton y que sólo se active el JButton cuando es seleccionado 1 JRadioButton

```
private void jRadioButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                           
       if(jRadioButton1.isSelected()){
           jButton1.setEnabled(true);           
       }
} 

private void jRadioButton2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                           
       if(jRadioButton2.isSelected()){
           jButton1.setEnabled(true);           
       }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo de verdad me ayudaste

Comment: Me alegro poder ayudar :)